# SQL Server Always On Availability Group Zero Downtime Update Procedure

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, sql-server-2016, alwayson

Here I have a 2-node SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn Availability Group cluster, with 1 primary and 1 secondary.

The question is - what is the optimal way to install Microsoft Updates on the servers in the cluster?  I have struggled to find good, clear recommendations on this.

Here is my current thinking:

1. Install updates using Microsoft Update on the secondary
2. Restart the secondary to finish the updates
3. Perform a manual failover from the Primary to the Secondary
4. Install updates using Microsoft Update on the new-secondary (former primary)
5. Restart the new-secondary (former primary)
6. Perform a manual failover from the new-Primary to the Secondary, making the original primary the primary again

My understanding is that this will:

- Cause absolutely no application downtime
- Cause no syncing errors
- Cause no data corruption
- The cluster will not generate errors when half the nodes are updated and the other half are not

Is this correct?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance - any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's a detailed procedure here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/upgrading-always-on-availability-group-replica-instances

Comment: @GregAskew Isn't this for Upgrade (i.e. Major Version) not update (patches)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve what you want:

[Apply SQL Server patches or cumulative updates in SQL Server Always On Availability Groups](https://www.sqlshack.com/apply-sql-server-patches-or-cumulative-updates-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-groups/)

You might scroll down right to the "**Preparatory Phase**" section skipping all the "water".

Comment: You're absolutely welcome!